# Каскадное удаление строк, если таблица одна

Tags: php, mysql

Есть одна таблица: forum. В ней создаются форумы и они между собой могут быть связаны по forum_id, в котором хранится id форума, в котором создан другой.
То есть зависимость может выстроиться так:

```
id - 1
id - 2, forum_id - 1
id - 3, forum_id - 1
id - 5, forum_id - 2 => forum_id - 1
id - 6, forum_id - 3 => forum_id - 1
id - 7, forum_id - 5 => forum_id - 2 => forum_id - 1
id - 8, forum_id - 7 => forum_id - 5 => forum_id - 2, forum_id - 1
```

К примеру, нужно удалить форум id - 1. Следом надо удалить ВСЕ строки, которые как-то связаны с ним... Но как?
Тот же id - 8 относится к id - 1, но ссылается сперва на id 7, тот на id 5, тот на id 2 и только этот на id 1...

Comment: для этого есть внешние ключи, на которые можно повесить каскадное удаление при удалении родителя

Comment: @ArchDemon я без понятия, как это сделать :) особенно когда и родитель, и детишки в одной таблице

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html обратите внимание на раздел Referential Actions

Comment: думаю в каждом комментарии должен храниться id темы форума, по нему и удалить все сообщения